# Cant generate php artisan key

Tags: php, mariadb, key, laravel-artisan, generate

Ia m trying to set up Snipe IT on Windows server 2016 (VM) . I stack on part where i need to generate key.

When i execute php artisan key:generate i get following error.I checked ".env" file and I think everything is correct. I tried with composer install and update but same error acours...

Does anyone now how to fix this issue ?
Many thanks in advance

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vUmBk.png

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean to generate application key?
`'key' => env('APP_KEY', 'SomeRandomString')` in file `app.php`
if you mean it then executes this command **`php artisan key:generate`**

Comment: Hi, thank you for you answer. In short iam setting up Snipe IT on WIndows server 2016. I tried with php artisan key:generate but i got error about invalid file. Path that was inside .env file was written with one backslash. 'C:\Program Files\Maria DB\bin'. i changed it to 'C:\\Program FIles\\Maria DB\\bin and key was generate after modifing env file with this.